# Problema de espaciado/margen derecho en página HTML

Tags: css, html5, css3, web

quisiera formular esta pregunta con respecto a un proyecto que estoy haciendo, una página web especificamente,el problema está en que la parte derecha de la página queda con un espacio en blanco y eso no permite ver el contenido del sitio web apropiadamente, voy a enseñar imagenes, tanto en vista normal como en vista para dispositivos celulares.

[image: Margen derecho sobresale]

[image: margen afecta proporción del pie de pagina]

Aqui se puede notar claramente como afecta este problema al pie de pagina

[image: aqui se nota el problema pero en vista de dispositivo movil]

Aqui el problema está más presente en la vista movil, pareciera que el html en su totalidad solo abarca esa parte de la página y todo lo demás pues lo omite. Me gustaría saber como podría resolver esta problemática. También voy a compartir el codigo, aunque esté en codepen, espero no haya inconveniente, es debido a que es algo extenso.

código html y css

```css
html {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', Arial;
    src: url(fuentes/JosefinSans-VariableFont_wght.ttf);
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Container de header */




.header-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 95%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1.8fr 1fr;
    max-height: 130px;
    
}

.logo > img {
    width: 100%;
    /* background-color: #f1f1f1; */
    object-fit: cover;
    max-height: 100%; 
    justify-self: self-start;
 }



.texto {
    margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
 }


 .vacio {
     color: black;
 }

.links {
    /* background-color: #f1f1f1; */
    margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
}

header a, li{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase ;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 4px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

header a.activo {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;   
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .logo > img {
        width: 170px;
        margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
    } 
}


/* Muestra grafica */

.muestra-grafica{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    /* height: 280px;  */
}

.muestra-grafica 

.muestra-grafica h1{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 60px;

}

.muestra-grafica p{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 280px) {
    .muestra-grafica{ 
        margin-right: -111px;
        margin-left: -10px;
        height: 100%;
        
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagina curso</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='estilo-copy1.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header-container">
            <div class="logo">  
                <img class="img-logo" src="imagenes/untitleddesign_1_original-1-removebg-preview.png" alt="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="texto">
                <h2>Instituto Venezolano</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="vacio">

            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <ul>
                    <div class="lista">
                    <li><a class="activo" href="#registro">Registro</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ingreso">Ingresar</a></li>
                    </div>              
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="muestra-grafica">
        <h1>¡Aprende algo nuevo hoy!</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi quae cum totam impedit eveniet sint blanditiis debitis</p>
    </section>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te invito a leer [mcve]. Deberías ser capaz de aislar el código mínimo para poder reproducir el problema. Un enlace externo al código no es bien recibido por la comunidad. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] y añadir lo que sea necesario. Saludos

Comment: Entiendo, mejor lo edito entonces, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Envuelve todo el contenido en un bloque contenedor (div) y a este bloque ponle margin:0 auto. En la muestra que pones se ve que ocupa todo el ancho de pantalla y tiene barra scroll inferior. Puede que tengas algun elemento definido con un ancho superior a la ventana. Así que al contenedor puedes ponerle un ancho del 80% o lo que veas.

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a intentar esto